# This expression was expected to have type bool but here has type unit error

Tags: f#

getting an error when I try to run this line of code and I can't figure out why

```
    let validCol column value : bool = 
        for i in 0..8 do
            if sudokuBoard.[i,column] = value then 
                false
            else true
```

Answer (score 2):

As Tyler Hartwig says a `for` loop cannot return a value except `unit`.

On the other hand, inside a list comprehension or a `seq` Computation Expression you can use `for` to `yield` the values and then test if the one you are looking for exists:

```
let validCol column value : bool = 
    seq { for i in 0..8 do yield sudokuBoard.[i,column] }
    |> Seq.exists value
    |> not
```

Answer (score 1):

In F#, the last call made is what is returned, you have explicitly declared you are returning a bool.

The `for` loop is unable to return or aggregate multiple values, bun instead, returns `unit`.

```
let validCol column value : bool = 
    for i in 0..8 do
        if sudokuBoard.[i,column] = value then 
            false
        else 
            true
```

Here, you'll need to figure out how to aggregate all the `bool` to get your final result. I'm not quite sure what this is supposed to return, or I'd give an example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for a short-cut out of the loop like in C# you can use `continue`, `break` or `return` to exit a loop.

In F# the way to accomplish that with performance is to use tail-recursion. You could achieve it with while loops but that requires mutable variables which tail-recursion doesn't need (although we sometimes uses it).

A tail-recursive function is one that calls itself at the very end and doesn't look at the result:

So this is tail-recursive

```
let rec loop acc i = if i > 0 then loop (acc + i) (i - 1) else acc
```

Where this isn't

```
let rec loop fib i = if i < 1 then 1 else fib (i - 1) + fib (i - 2)
```

If F# compiler determines a function is tail-recursive the compiler applies tail-recursion optimization (TCO) on the function, basically it unrolls it into an efficient for loop that looks a lot like the loop would like in C#.

So here is one way to write `validCol` using tail-recursion:

```
let validCol column value : bool =
  // loops is tail-recursive
  let rec loop column value i =
    if i < 9 then
      if sudokuBoard.[i,column] = value then 
        false // The value already exists in the column, not valid
      else
        loop column value (i + 1)  // Check next row.
    else
      true  // Reach the end, the value is valid
  loop column value 0
```

Unfortunately; F# compiler doesn't have an attribute to force TCO (like Scala or kotlin does) and therefore if you make a slight mistake you might end up with a function that isn't TCO. I think I saw GitHub issue about adding such an attribute.

PS. `seq` comprehensions are nice in many cases but for a sudoku solver I assume you are looking for something that is as fast as possible. `seq` comprehensions (and LINQ) I think adds too much overhead for a sudoku solver whereas tail-recursion is about as quick as you can get in F#.

PS. In .NET 2D arrays are slower than 1D arrays, just FYI. Unsure if it has improved with dotnet core.